# Find multiple instances of a string in a text file - python

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to find multiple instances of a string in a text file but i can only work out a way to find the first instance. I've tried various while and for loops to no avail and i'm stuck for answers. What is the most efficient way to do this in python?

```
movinf = open("movinf.txt", "a")
        match = re.search('"string":([^,]+)', name)
        if match:
            result = match.group(1)
            movinf.write(result + "\n")
        else:
            pass
        movinf.close()
```

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion you're trying to parse a JSON file with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only running the blocks once and therefore only getting one result. Use `re.findall` instead:

```
match = re.findall('"string":([^,]+)', name)
if len(match) > 0:
    movinf.write("\n".join(match))
movinf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
p = re.pattern('"string":([^,]+)')
print p.findall(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Folowing program use simple file and list operation :

```
str1 = raw_input("Enter the string you want to search : ")
with open("C:\\Users\\priyank\\Desktop\\movinf.txt","r") as movinf:
    listp = movinf.readlines()
count =0
for i in range(0, len(listp)):
    if str1 in listp[i]:
        # do something
        count=count+1
print "number of word exist in file :" + str(count)
```